# iterating over things in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object

I have an array called $options.
I want iterate through it's contents, so I do:

```
 foreach($options as $option){   
    print_r( $option);
 }
```

The resulting output gives me an object/array heffalump that starts like this...

```
Mage_Bundle_Model_Option Object
(
    [_defaultSelection:protected] => 
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
    [_eventObject:protected] => object
    [_resourceName:protected] => bundle/option
    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 20
            [parent_id] => 291
```

I want to reference values in _data, but I am stumped as to correct syntax to do this...

Comment: what is a heffalump??

Comment: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Bundle/Mage_Bundle_Model_Option.html

Comment: Protected properties can only be accessed by the class or its relatives.

Comment: [heffalump](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLnADKgurvc)

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge: You never read Winnie the Pooh?

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge By the sounds of your name you spent more time on Ali Baba and the 40 Thieves

Comment: ah, names can be deceiving. You see YasserGoldberg was already taken.

Comment: do tell what heffalump has to do with arrays and objects?

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge I didn't know a heffalump either, but having watched the video, I guess it can be everything (or change into anything?). OP saying "object/array heffalump" probably means he doesn't exactly know what he is dealing with (is it an object? is it an array? no, it's a heffalump)

Comment: Heffalump = Thingummyjig = Doodah = Wotsit. All clear? Good, as you were. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's no syntax to access them from generic code. The `Mage_Bundle_Model_Option` class has declared its properties as *protected*, which means they can only be accessed from the class, its decendants, or its ancestors. You should use the class's public methods to make use of it, not access the properties directly.

Answer (score 0):

because the _data object is set as `protected`, it can only be accessed from inside the `Mage_Bundle_Model_Option` class or one that extends from it.

so what you would have to do is add a method inside Mage_Bundle_Model_Option along the lines of

```
function getData(){
 return $this->_data;
}
```

and then instead of your current foreach loop, do:

```
foreach($options->getData() as $option) {
   //do things
}
```